# ngrx ofType, @ngrx/effects

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-effects

i try to understand how typeof effects work under the hood in ngrx,
if i declare in my app module:

```
....

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        EffectsModule.forRoot([TodosEffectsService])
],

....
```

and i write effect file sure:

```
@Effect() createTodos$ = this.actions$
.ofType(CREATE_TASK)
    .map(() => {
        console.log('called');
            return { type: 'OTHER'};
});

@Effect() addTodos$ = this.actions$
.ofType(CREATE_TASK)
    .map(() => {
        console.log('called');
            return { type: 'OTHER'};
});
```

i try to understand, now in run time i dispatch a action
this.action$ is subscribed and every time execute ofType to match the type?
or ofType once execute!?

if it called once, when i dispatch action how effects know every time witch effect to subscribe/execute?

thank all!

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cyaAhXHhxgk this might be helpful

Comment: they are explain how to use effects, not how it work under the hood. i try to understand how it cached the action type and if it subscribe every time all effects actions and find the action type

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In a nutshell, when `.ofType()` gets called, it subscribes to the source stream of actions and pushes matching actions to the resulting stream. So it is indeed called once.

If we look at the [source code](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/modules/effects/src/actions.ts#L136), we'll see that under the hood `ofType` uses `filter` operator of `rxjs` library, meaning that `this.action$.ofType(CREATE_TASK)` can be expanded to

```
this.action$.filter(action => action.type === CREATE_TASK)
```

Description of how `filter` works can be found from `rxjs` [docs](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js%7EObservable.html#instance-method-filter):

> Similar to the well-known `Array.prototype.filter` method, this operator takes values from the source Observable, passes them through a `predicate` function and only emits those values that yielded `true`.

It's worth noting that each of your effects takes an observable (`this.action$`) as input and returns a new observable which is subscribed only once, when effects are initialized. That returned observable defines the way how actions from the input observable are transformed, but it does not affect the source observable itself.

In your example `ofType()` method returns a new observable that "listens" to `this.action$` observable and emits only actions that satisfy the condition `action.type === CREATE_TASK`. Then goes the `map` operator, it also returns a new observable which "listens" to the observable returned by `ofType()` call and transforms each action it receives to a new value according to a projection function you pass. But all of those observables are created only once, upon initialization, and when you dispatch actions, they just "flow" through observables, get filtered and transformed.

You might also want to become more familiar with `rxjs`. I would recommend you to check ["You will learn RxJS"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uQ1zhJHclvs) talk by André Staltz, it should give you an intuition of what observables are and how they work.

Comment: thank you for response, so if i use store.dispatch({ type: CREAT_TASK, payload: payload}); every time i dispatch an action,  this.action$ is execute all effects(returned observable) and check(filter) if type is correct?

Comment: If you have `N` epics each of which is using `.ofType()`, then typically the predicate `allowedTypes.some(type => type === action.type)` will be executed `N` types, which is fine unless you have millions of epics registered or millions of allowed action types passed (and I guess it's not the case). If the filter does not accept an action, callbacks of the chained operators (e.g. the function you pass to `map()`) will not be executed. I would say that you should not be concerned with the `ofType()` performance, just don't create millions of epics : )

Comment: yes of course, maybe i do not have a millions of allowed action types passed, but for big scale application, we have 30 epics for module, any small action like(checkd/uncheckd) every time all epics executed :\ i think they was can to save type as hash and call for the specific  epic

never mind i don't the ngrx contributor so .... :)

Comment: @SergeyKaravaev - sorry, but what is `epic` in this context?

Comment: @ebhh2001, sorry for the confusion, `epic` is the term used in [redux-observable](https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/basics/Epics.html) middleware for redux. In `ngrx-effects` epics are called "effects".

Answer (score 2):

this.actions$
.ofType(CREATE_TASK) will call every time when your action get dispatched, after your reducer case get execute. 
like 
Redcucer

```
switch(action) {
case youractionsname.CREATE_TASK : {
// pure function logic here
   }
}
```

First reducer will execute and then it will look into effect, if you have any effect who has type of 'CREATE_TASK'.
In subscription pattern whatever you have subscribe that will be call back function and it will store in array under the hood based on condition. When you dispatch action based on condition that all function will call who meet the condition.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that the ofType is not exported in Actions class inside the ngrx/effects
so you can use it like following:
1- import  ofType from ngrx/effects which would be

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

import { Effect, Actions, ofType } from "@ngrx/effects";
import * as omid from "@ngrx/effects";
import { of } from "rxjs";
import { map, switchMap, catchError } from "rxjs/operators";
@Injectable()
export class PizzasEffects {
  constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private pizzaService: frtomServices.PizzasService
  ) {}

  @Effect()
  LoadPizzas$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(pizzaActions.LOAD_PIZZAS),
    switchMap(() => {
      return this.pizzaService.getPizzas().pipe(
        map(pizzas => new pizzaActions.LoadPizzasSuccess(pizzas)),
        catchError(error => of(new pizzaActions.LoadPizzasFail(error)))
      );
    })
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also dispatch an array of actions from each effect.

[Read this article from medium](https://udimaz.medium.com/dispatch-multiple-actions-from-a-single-effect-using-an-action-array-50596fd8aee9)